# I accidently deleted my python project, it is running on IDE

Tags: python

**I accidently deleted my python project by mistake and it is still running in the IDE, but i lost all the files.**

tried the recovery tools and i can't get them back , is there any way to recover them?

**IN Windows**

tried the recovery tools and i can't get them back

Comment: What do you mean by "idle"? Do you mean the IDE?

Comment: It's OK. You can get it all back from your backup disk

Comment: yes it is a typo, i meant ide,

Comment: If you have the files open in the IDE just click File, Save As  and save each file. And remember to make a backup of your code.

Comment: I have only the main.py open , other files in the project are not

Comment: If you don't have a backup then there's nothing you can do